# Set LayoutParams.BELOW programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to set `LayoutParams.BELOW` programmatically. Here my code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this.getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCDCDCD"));

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.create_template);

    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

    if (frameAnimation != null) {
        frameAnimation.start();
    }

    TextView textView = new TextView(this.getActivity());
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText("Generating information...");

    layout.addView(imageView);
    layout.addView(textView);

    return layout;
```

But it's not being correctly positioned. Any idea on why it is not well positioned?

Comment: You posted the wrong code. No "below" to see, just "above". Does your imageview have an id?

Comment: Sorry, even below or above are not working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ImageView` doesn't have an ID. You need to give it one. Either define some constant integer value, or use [`View.generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()), and call `setId()` before using it in the layout params:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
...
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
```